# Read csv files in multiple zip files by using one csv as an example and loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have multiple zip files in a folder and within the zip files are multiple csv files.
All csv files dont have all the columns but a few have all the columns.
How can I use the file that has all the columns as an example and then loop it to extract all the data into one dataframe and save it into one csv for further use?

The code I am following right now is as below:

```
import glob
import zipfile
import pandas as pd


dfs = []
for zip_file in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\harsh\Desktop\Temp\*.zip"):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file)
    dfs += [pd.read_csv(zf.open(f), sep=";", encoding='latin1') for f in zf.namelist()]
    df = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)


print(df)
```

However, I am not getting the columns and headers at all. I am stuck at this stage.

If you'd like to know the file structure,

Please find the [output of the code here](http://wikisend.com/download/596782/Current_output.csv) and

The [example csv file here](http://wikisend.com/download/694092/Expected_output.csv).

If you would like to see my project files for this code, Please find the [shared google drive link here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OdNtJKRyS09Ws_73ovhqKwjj8aftb9mm)

Also, at the risk of sounding redundant, why am I required to use the `sep=";", encoding='latin1'` part? The code gives me an error without it otherwise.

Comment: the sep and encoding are as such because the input files are stored in this way, you just need to keep them.

Comment: You may want to specify necessary parameters when you read_csv, please refer to the API here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the default parameters (pandas reading all columns as string) dont apply in my case?

Comment: the only file i am able to download is `/Current_output.csv`. No source data file

Comment: Oh, so sorry for that. Please find all project files below. Current output: http://wikisend.com/download/596782/Current_output.csv, Expected output: http://wikisend.com/download/694092/Expected_output.csv and all the zip files as stored in google drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OdNtJKRyS09Ws_73ovhqKwjj8aftb9mm Please let me know if you are able to access all of them

Comment: Yes, it should apply in your case. You just need to figure out the column names to make your output the same as your desired one.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how can I reference the column names and then loop?